# Store tr's ID and Class into a js array and read it in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a table with a bunch of kids, and in each tr I have the ID of the child and the class describing what did he eat, I need that when I click one button the id and class of every row must be stored into a js array, I've been trying storing into an array with push and stuffs like this...

```
var array = [];

$("#tbody tr").each(function() {
  array.push(this.id);
});
```

but with no luck 'cause I need two values and it explodes...

here's the table structure

```
<table class="table -dark -striped" id="datatable"> 
 <thead> 
   <tr> 
    <th class="col -xs-9 -lg-9 -xl-9 _text-right">Nombre del Alumno</th>
      <th class="col -xs-3 -lg-3 -xl-3">Asistencia</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody id='tbody'>                  
    <tr id="1" class="lunch"> 
       <td class="-user -detailed _text-right">Richard Mattey</td>
       <td class="_text-right">
         <div class="btn-group asistencia">
              <a class="btn -l -dark -block lunch" href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="lunch">Lunch</a>
              <a class="btn -l -dark -block vianda -success"  href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="vianda">Vianda</a>
              <a class="btn -l -dark -block inasistente" href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="inasistente"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
         </div>
      </td>                  
   </tr>
```

When I click lunch or vianda, the corresponding TR gets a class with the name of the food:

```
$(document).on("click", ".asistencia a.btn", function () {

            if ($(this).hasClass("-success")){ } 
            else {
                    var elIDdelAlumnoQuelediClick = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); 
                    var servicioDelBoton = $(this).attr('servicio');
                    $("#" + elIDdelAlumnoQuelediClick + " .asistencia a.btn").removeClass("-success");
                    $("#" + elIDdelAlumnoQuelediClick + " .asistencia a.btn." + servicioDelBoton).addClass("-success");
                    $("#" + elIDdelAlumnoQuelediClick).removeClass("inasistente");
                    $("#" + elIDdelAlumnoQuelediClick).attr('class' , servicioDelBoton);
                }
        });
```

What I need is to store into a JS Array the two values of each `tr` (id and class) and then send it by ajax when I click the save button, and after that get it in PHP to process it...

Comment: What have you tried? All you have stated is an objective but not any code related problem achieving that goal. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I'm Sorry about my mistakes I just edited it, it's like my third time asking, and I've already found a solution, ty for ur sugestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fetch the ids and classes of each `tr` entry in your table by using the following function:

```
/* The function that fetches the data. */
function fetchData() {
   var
      /* Create an object to store the data. */
      data = {},

      /* Get every 'tr' element of the 'tbody'. */
      elements = document.querySelectorAll("#tbody > tr");

      /* For each element, save the id as a property & the class as a value in the obj. */
      [].forEach.call(elements, (element) => data[element.id] = element.className);

   /* Stringify and return the data to pass them over to the server. */
   return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

The above function stores the data as property-value pairs in an object and also stringifies the object, so that you can pass that to the server. Then you can easily the access in PHP with a `foreach as` construct:

**Example:**

```
foreach ($data as $id => $class) {
   # ...
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* The function that fetches the data. */
function fetchData() {
  var
    /* Create an object to store the data. */
    data = {},

    /* Get every 'tr' element of the 'tbody'. */
    elements = document.querySelectorAll("#tbody > tr");

  /* For each element, save the id as a property & the class as a value in the obj. */
  [].forEach.call(elements, (element) => data[element.id] = element.className);

  /* Stringify and return the data to pass them over to the server. */
  return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

```html
<table class="table -dark -striped" id="datatable">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody id='tbody'>
    <tr id="1" class="lunch"></tr>
    <tr id="2" class="breakfast"></tr>
    <tr id="3" class="brunch"></tr>
    <tr id="4" class="dinner"></tr>
    <tr id="5" class="supper"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick = "console.log(fetchData())">Fetch Table Data</button>
```

Comment: thanks! I had to edit it a bit! but it works! :), at the end it is like this:  
/* For each element, save the id as a property & the class as a value in the obj. */
[].forEach.call(elements, (element) => data[0] = element.className);
[].forEach.call(elements, (element) => data[1] = element.id);

Comment: I'm glad I could help @gamn2090. Beware though, as your edit actually overwrites the `0` and `1` properties of the object every loop. Give a look at my edit to see what I mean.

Comment: but If I do it like that I got this:
`index:["1", "lunch"]`
and in php I need to access each one of it, and it does not work if I do this:

`if($request->ajax()){
            $post      = $request->all();
            foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
                print_r($value);
            }
        }`

Comment: Before you edited your question, it seemed to me like you wanted to pass the `ids` and `classes` of all `tr` elements of the table to the server. Now, it's obvious that you only want the one `tr` element whose button was clicked and things are completely different in this case. Check my edited answer out to see how you achieve this simply.

Comment: no no, What u undertood was what I wanted to do >.<, get all the ID and Class of the table's trs

Comment: Okay. I guess your last sentence confused me. I edited it to clear any confusion. Since you want the data of every `tr`, then my original answer will give you what you want. The change you made in your first comment will not work, if the table has more than one `tr` element. In your code in the question, you have only used one. Try testing it with more `tr` elements and you'll see your code fails. If it works, fine. You're probably doing something that you haven't shown us here that makes it work as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to execute a function for each `tr` element, and get the id and class values:

```
var arr = [];

$('#tbody tr').each( function (i, tr) {

    arr.push({ 
        id: $(tr).attr('id'), 
        class: $(tr).attr('class') 
    });

});
```

**OR** you can use jQuery [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function to iterate over all `tr` elements and construct your array:

```
var arr2 = $.map( $('#tbody tr'), function (tr) {
    return {
       id: $(tr).attr('id'), 
       class: $(tr).attr('class') 
    }
});
```

Here is a working example:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // using each function

  var arr = [];
  
  $('#tbody tr').each( function (i, tr) {
  
    arr.push({ 
      id: $(tr).attr('id'), 
      class: $(tr).attr('class') 
    });
    
  });
  
  console.log(arr);
  
  // using jquery map function
    
  var arr2 = $.map( $('#tbody tr'), function (tr) {
    return {
       id: $(tr).attr('id'), 
       class: $(tr).attr('class') 
    }
  });
    
  console.log(arr2);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table -dark -striped" id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col -xs-9 -lg-9 -xl-9 _text-right">Nombre del Alumno</th>
      <th class="col -xs-3 -lg-3 -xl-3">Asistencia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tbody'>
    <tr id="1" class="lunch">
      <td class="-user -detailed _text-right">Richard Mattey</td>
      <td class="_text-right">
        <div class="btn-group asistencia">
          <a class="btn -l -dark -block lunch" href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="lunch">Lunch</a>
          <a class="btn -l -dark -block vianda -success" href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="vianda">Vianda</a>
          <a class="btn -l -dark -block inasistente" href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="inasistente"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the `tr`'s that are in `tbody` with `querySelectorAll`.

Then just collect the id & class name from the DomNode, something like that:

```js
const trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr'));

const data = trs.map((tr) => ({
  id: tr.id,
  class: tr.classList.toString()
}));

console.log(data);
```

```html
<table class="table -dark -striped" id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col -xs-9 -lg-9 -xl-9 _text-right">Nombre del Alumno</th>
      <th class="col -xs-3 -lg-3 -xl-3">Asistencia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tbody'>
    <tr id="1" class="lunch">
      <td class="-user -detailed _text-right">Richard Mattey</td>
      <td class="_text-right">
        <div class="btn-group asistencia">
          <a class="btn -l -dark -block lunch" href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="lunch">Lunch</a>
          <a class="btn -l -dark -block vianda -success" href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="vianda">Vianda</a>
          <a class="btn -l -dark -block inasistente" href="javascript:void(0)" servicio="inasistente"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```